# How can I deploy react application on azure windows VM using azure devops release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I have created build pipeline successfully for react application but not able to deploy that build artifact on windows VM. Is there any way to deploy react build on windows VM using azure release pipeline ?

Want to create release pipeline to deploy react build on azure windows VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have tried to repro the same using the below steps and I got positive results.**

**Step 1:** Create Azure Virtual Machine and Install Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager on VM as shown below and verify.

[image]

After installing the IIS, go to the browser and enter localhost, you will see the below image.

[image]

**Step 2:** Go to Azure DevOps > Pipelines > Deployment Groups to create a new
deployment group and copy the power shell script.

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Note: If you do not enable the “Use a personal access token in the script for authentication”, You must create it manually and paste it while running the script in the VM.*

**Step 3:** Go to VM > power shell > paste the script and run with default values.

[image]

Once you successfully run the script in the VM, you will see the VM is online in Azure DevOps.

[image]

**Step 4:** Go to Release pipelines > Click new pipeline and select IIS Website Deployment template.

[image]

[image]

Select the deployment group you have created in **step 2.**

[image]

The physical path in the above screenshot is the default path where the deployment files will fall. If you have any custom hosting path other than this you can change it.

Make sure you have given the right path for the a rtefacts folder to deploy.

**Step 5:** Run the pipeline and check the output.

[image]